# Turned Based Game with Servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I want to make a turn based game (Something like Checkers) with the help of Servlets and jsp pages.I created a page that has a newGame button that redircet to the gamePage(It redirect the first into a Black.jsp and the other request will be redirected to Red.jsp).

My problem is ,how could I refresh the other jsp automaticaly if one of them changed.

Note:After the change in one of the jsp it redirect the request to servlet and servlet update the changed jsp graphics.but the other jsp stay inactive.I want to make it active.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is Comet. Here's an overview of how it works.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/

Basically, the "other" user's browser will send a request to a servlet to get an update, but that request won't receive receive its response until the current player makes a move. This gets around the problem posed by the fact that, with traditional HTTP, the browser always has to be the one sending the request to the server, it can't be the other way around.

There are some variations on the technique. Now that you know the name, I'm sure you'll be able to find lots of useful information about it.

There's another technology called [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) which can also serve this purpose, but it requires additional capability built into the browser and, as of now, probably not all of your users will be using compatible browsers.